# how to prevent common values from two different tables ( 2 table with 1-to-1 relation with a third table)

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, relationship, one-to-one

So basically i have two entity tables Employees and Customers they both have a 1 to 1 relationship with a third Table Cars. So there should be no duplicates of the same cars in table employees and no duplicate in Customers table. This went fine with me , however i cant prevent from having the same car being in the both tables like for example below

```
Employees Table
SocialNo | FirstName | LastName | LicencePlate | Other  
14256335 | John      | Wick     | 213546       | bla bla  
12348596 | Sara      | Milles   |              | bla bla  
18596563 | Leo       | Cranes   | 185647       | bla bla   <--------
                                                                   |
                                                               |

Customer Table                                                     |  
SocialNo | FirstName | LastName | LicencePlate | Other  
14256335 | Jack      | Cooper   | 200000       | bla bla           |
12348596 | Danial    | Foker    | 300054       | bla bla           |
18596563 | Brian     | B.James  | 185647       | bla bla  <---------


Car
Licence  | Model     | Department | Other  
200000   | Toyota    | SAles      | bla bla  
300054   | Fiat      | IT         | bla bla  
185647   | Spranza   | Accountant | bla bla <-- this shouldnt shared in EMp and Customer tables
213546   | Toyota    | Sales      | bla bla
```

So as u see there is no duplicates of cars itself in any of the tables however the access data entry allow for having the same car in both Employees and Customers table, how to make MS access show error message like entering duplicate data of car licence plate twice in any other table ?? Im using MS access 2016 .

Comment: Use VBA to validate record during data entry. Or have one table for all People.

Comment: Isn't there a work around but VBA, can you provide an example code ??

Comment: Can use DLookup() domain aggregate function to look for value in other table when doing data entry for one table. Use some event behind form, perhaps BeforeUpdate of LicencePlate combobox. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question. Or restructure db as suggested. Or save SocialNo into Cars table instead of LicencePlate in other tables.